# How to put last edited entry on top of the blog-post list?

Tags: posts, order, date, list

In the list of my blog posts, the "last published" entry is on top. I'd like to view the "last edited" entry on top of that list.

I couldn't find a setting for that, so how can I realize it?

Comment: Use `pre_get_posts` with `$query->set ( 'orderby', 'modified' );`

Comment: The solution by @PieterGoosen should work fine. You can also modify the order with e.g. `example.com/?orderby=modified&order=desc` if you want to test the ordering and play without coding ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen: Where Do I have to put those commands, when I'd like to modify the default behaviour of my startpage? Can you please write an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I'm not able to post code right now as I'm posting from my phone. Will post a full answer a bit later when I'm at home :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen are you back home?

Comment: Sorry Edward, to be honest, I really forgot about this. My sincere apologies. I will definitely try to post a solution ASAP, will still be toaday. Just one quick question, @birgire suggested to play with the URL first. Did that gave you the desired output with the sorting order.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Yes, the solution from birgire sorted the entries in the correct order. I also added a link to my bookmarks, as long as this is not the default behaviour of my blog :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in my comment to the OP, you should make use of [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to target change the query variables as needed before the main query is executed.

Just a tip, `pre_get_posts` uses the same exact parameters as [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), so you can have a look at those parameters and use them to construct your `pre_get_post` action parameters to modify the query variables

To achieve what you are after, you need to look at the `orderby` and `order` parameters, you will want to use the value of `modified` for the parameter `orderby`.

Remember, with `pre_get_posts` you can target specific pages/templates by means of the [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags). However, this will not work on if your page you want to target is a static front page, then you will need to use `WP_Query` to construct a custom query with the desired parameters

You can try something like this in your functions.php. Here I am going to target only the home page

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'modified' );
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer solved my problem, thanks. I'll also give it a +1, once I reached 15 reputation.

Comment: No problem. Enjoy :-)